# How to compute a getter in vue?

Tags: vue.js, if-statement, vuejs2, getter, computed-properties

I'm expecting to display a computed getter property, but VSC gives me the error "Expected to return a value in 'features' computed property." Even though I'm returnng a true value in getter in code.

```js
// Doesn't work
computed: {
    features() {
      if(this.$store.getters.features) {        // feature is definately true by itsels (returns true)
        return this.$store.getters.features   // error comes here
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Works fine
computed: {
    features() {
        return this.$store.getters.features 
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The way it's supposed to be written depends on the expected "features" value. You didn't explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle the `else` case :

```js
computed: {
    features() {
      if(this.$store.getters.features) {       
        return this.$store.getters.features   
      } else{
       return false;
      }
    }
```

but it's recommended to use the second syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In a computed property, you should always ensure that a value is returned, no matter what condition is met.

In your computed property, you have an `if` statement that checks if `this.$store.getters.features` is `truthy`, and if it is, it returns the value. However, if the condition is not met (if `this.$store.getters.features` is `falsy`), the function does not return anything, which is the cause of the error.

Example **:**

```
computed: {
  features() {
    if (this.$store.getters.features) {
      return this.$store.getters.features;
    } else {
      return null; // You can use any return value here as per requirement
    }
  }
}
```